# What to check before rebuilding a Sitecore index via scheduled task?

Tags: solr, indexing

I'm trying to do something that I don't see a lot of descriptions of.

For our installation of Sitecore, we have a special index, for managing pictures via a service called "Digizuite".

This index breaks once in a while, and then needs to be reindexed. We have not been able to determine why, but maybe we will at some point, who knows.

But, in order to fix the issue more acutely, we decided to create a command in Sitecore that we could start via a Sitecore scheduled task, and then reindex it once a day.

So, I have created a command that points to a method in  the code, and then is started via a scheduled task.

The code I have written so far looks like this:

```csharp
public void Execute()
{
    RebuildIndexes("dfs_assets_master_index");
    RebuildIndexes("dfs_assets_web_index");
}

private void RebuildIndexes(string indexName)
{
    var index = GetIndex(indexName);
    var indexstate = index.IndexingState;

    if (indexstate == IndexingState.Started)
    {
        index.Rebuild();
        indexstate = index.IndexingState;
    }
}
```

Where I basically check the state of the index, and if it is not already running, then I run rebuild on it.

The only check I have implemented for avoiding double-indexing is to check whether the index is not stopped or paused. But could I implement some other important checks? such as checking the last index of the rebuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to run this as scheduled job, so you can ensure that there is a sufficient gap between the last run and the new run. You could perhaps run it once a day. So, I feel that there is no need to check the index state.

1. You should have a null check in place for `indexName`. If the indexName is empty or null, you should return.
2. You could add `try-catch` clause so that if the jobs fails you get to know about it by checking the logs.
3. You should also include additional `logging` comments like "Starting indexing for {indexName}" at the start of the function and "Finished indexing for {indexName}" at the end.

Comment: thx, I'll include those checks!